# One or more invalid package name(s). Make sure package names are associated with a valid Google Play store URL

Tags: kotlin, facebook, facebook-login

I'm having trouble configuring Facebook login for Kotlin App according to website address "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android". I want to add "Package Name" in step 5 of "Associate Your Package Name and Default Class with Your App" but display the message as shown below.
[image]

Can someone give me a solution to fix it, I make sure that the name of the package is correct for the application I am developing

Answer (score 12):

*Meta now requires all NEWLY entered package names to be associated with a valid google play store URL*. Therefore, we cannot test our Android apps if we don't have ours in Google Play Store. I really don't understand this Meta's decision.

[Meta comment](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1307870196812047/?join_id=f12e5a3b52a432)

Answer (score 4):

As per Meta guidelines, the New package must be available on the play store, so without uploading the app on the play store we can not use Facebook Login our application.

I have Solved this issue by

1. Go to Playstore and copy the bundle Id Of any app (I recommended using your own Android app bundle ID.) For Ex. You have published one app using com.example.app copy this bundle id.
2. In MainActivity use your own app id like com.example2.NewApp.MainActivity

It's working as expected I have integrated facebook login to new app using this way.

Comment: would the bundle id be editable afterwards?

Comment: Yes, It will be editable. I have checked and I can edit it

Answer (score 3):

[Meta's Reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWXFa.png)
Now we simply cant add facebook login feature until we have a Play Store Account Associated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same error, after searching I find that Facebook is now required that you **upload the app to the Play Store first** then after that, you can use this functionality.

Comment: I dont think so, its clealy says that 

`You can find this in your Android Manifest or your app's build.gradle file.`

Comment: In meta app console package name not adding until app available in google play.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I bypassed it using a Play store submited app package URL, after that app release I m changing that existing url to the original app package that needs to use