# Facebook-Login for internal test (Google Play Console) possible?

Tags: flutter, firebase, facebook-login, google-play-console

I have an app in the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) in the early stage as internal test. I tried to use Facebook login but Facebook complains that the package name is not valid. Is it a general problem that internal tests don't have a saved package name yet? or are public in the play store?

[image]

Comment: Is this GUI in Facebook or Google Play console? Can you give me link of this GUI?

Comment: it´s the facebook GUI, tody I found this, maybe it's because the package name is not fixed for internal tests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345578/one-or-more-invalid-package-names-make-sure-package-names-are-associated-with